Hazelcast with hibernate and spring doesn't work with lazyInitialization no session error
Hello guys i have a big problem with hazelcast 5.3 and hibernate 5.6 and spring boot 2.7, when calling a cacheable method i'm getting a no session error when retrieving data from cache, my problem is in my hazelcast configuration but i don't know where the error is comming from can someone please help ?
here is my hazelcast configuration
    @Configuration
    public class HazelCastConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Config hazelcastConfig() {
        Config config = new Config();

config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(true);
        
config.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        
        final UserCodeDeploymentConfig distCLConfig = config.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
        distCLConfig.setEnabled(true)
                .setClassCacheMode(UserCodeDeploymentConfig.ClassCacheMode.ETERNAL)
                .setProviderMode(UserCodeDeploymentConfig.ProviderMode.LOCAL_CLASSES_ONLY);

        config.addMapConfig(rajouterConfig("produits",5000,0));
        
        return config;
    }
    
    private MapConfig rajouterConfig(String nomCache, int taille, int tempsDeVie){
        return new MapConfig()
                .setName(nomCache)
                .setTimeToLiveSeconds(tempsDeVie)
                .setEvictionConfig(new EvictionConfig()
                        .setSize(taille)
                        .setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.PER_NODE)
                        .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance());
    }`

my spring methode is only a simple cacheable methode like this:
    @Cacheable(value=CACHE_MANAGER, keyGenerator = TrMethodAndParamsKeyGenerator.TR_KEY_GENERATOR_NAME , unless="#result == null or #result.size()==0") public List<ProfilQuestionEntite> recupererParModele(String profilModeleQuestion, String codeCategorie) {...}
}
when removing my hazelcast configuration class it works but i want to use hazelcast in my projet, something wrong with my configuration and i can't find what is the problem
the error is this that i'm having on second call:
no Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.e.#2] - no Session

the solution is just to create a bean of type
 @Bean
    public Config cacheConfig() {...}

this will automatically take hazelcast as the main cache.
we need to remove also the two beans :
  @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance());
    }`

